# Spring Many to Many with Extra Column Problem (detached entity passed to persist)

Tags: java, spring

I am calling this method:

```
private void createKoktelAndSastojci(AppDAO appDAO) {
        
        Koktel tmpKoktel = new Koktel("Naziv", "Opis", "NacinPripreme");
        System.out.println("Saving the Koktel entity...");
        appDAO.saveKoktel(tmpKoktel);
        System.out.println("Koktel entity saved with ID: " + tmpKoktel.getId());

        System.out.println("Fetching the Koktel entity from the database...");
        tmpKoktel = appDAO.findKoktelById(tmpKoktel.getId());


        System.out.println("Saving Sastojak entities...");
        Sastojak tmpSastojak1 = new Sastojak("Secer");
        Sastojak tmpSastojak2 = new Sastojak("Zasladjivac");
        Sastojak tmpSastojak3 = new Sastojak("Limun");
        appDAO.saveSastojak(tmpSastojak1);
        appDAO.saveSastojak(tmpSastojak2);
        appDAO.saveSastojak(tmpSastojak3);
        tmpSastojak1 = appDAO.findSastojakById(tmpSastojak1.getId());
        tmpSastojak2 = appDAO.findSastojakById(tmpSastojak2.getId());
        tmpSastojak3 = appDAO.findSastojakById(tmpSastojak3.getId());
        System.out.println("Done!");


        System.out.println("Saving KoktelSastojak entities...");
        KoktelSastojak koktelSastojak1 = new KoktelSastojak(tmpKoktel, tmpSastojak1, 100, "gr");
        KoktelSastojak koktelSastojak2 = new KoktelSastojak(tmpKoktel, tmpSastojak2, 1, "kom");
        KoktelSastojak koktelSastojak3 = new KoktelSastojak(tmpKoktel, tmpSastojak3, 2, "kom");

        appDAO.saveKoktelSastojak(koktelSastojak1);
        appDAO.saveKoktelSastojak(koktelSastojak2);
        appDAO.saveKoktelSastojak(koktelSastojak3);
        System.out.println("Done!");

    }
```

And i am getting an error saying: detached entity passed to persist

My KoktelSastojak class looks like this:

```
package com.fpis.fontazija.kokteli.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "koktel_sastojak")
public class KoktelSastojak {

    @EmbeddedId
    private KoktelSastojakKey id = new KoktelSastojakKey();

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("koktelId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "koktel_id")
    private Koktel koktel;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("sastojakId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "sastojak_id")
    private Sastojak sastojak;

    @Column(name = "kolicina")
    private float kolicina;

    @Column(name = "merna_jedinica")
    private String mernaJedinica;

    public KoktelSastojak() {}

    public KoktelSastojak(Koktel koktel, Sastojak sastojak, float kolicina, String mernaJedinica) {
        this.koktel = koktel;
        this.sastojak = sastojak;
        this.kolicina = kolicina;
        this.mernaJedinica = mernaJedinica;
    }

    public KoktelSastojakKey getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(KoktelSastojakKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Koktel getKoktel() {
        return koktel;
    }

    public void setKoktel(Koktel koktel) {
        this.koktel = koktel;
    }

    public Sastojak getSastojak() {
        return sastojak;
    }

    public void setSastojak(Sastojak sastojak) {
        this.sastojak = sastojak;
    }

    public float getKolicina() {
        return kolicina;
    }

    public void setKolicina(float kolicina) {
        this.kolicina = kolicina;
    }

    public String getMernaJedinica() {
        return mernaJedinica;
    }

    public void setMernaJedinica(String mernaJedinica) {
        this.mernaJedinica = mernaJedinica;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KoktelSastojak{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", koktel=" + koktel +
                ", sastojak=" + sastojak +
                ", kolicina=" + kolicina +
                ", mernaJedinica='" + mernaJedinica + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I created separate class KoktelSastojakKey for handling double primary key values.
My diagram looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP4eN.png)

I don't see what is the problem, can you help me?

I want to save all rows in the table as expected with the best pratice possible.
But i am getting an error saying: detached entity passed to persist.